Как настроить динамическое определение веса при балансировке нагрузки nginx
Я смог найти только способ явного задания весов для каждого сервера с помощью директивы server... weight=2, но по тз мне нужно определять веса динамически (dynamic weighted round robin). Как я могу это сделать?
